# Nesting Angular component inside nested component

Tags: angular, nested, components

guys!

My problem is that I have component nested inside another component which is component for a route. It's something like this: (Main component with `router-outlet`) **AppComponent -> LeaderComponent -> NavigationPathComponent**. Inside this last component I use `@Input()` to retrieve some values from parent and it works inside component code but not in template.

Here is my code:
`NavigationPathComponent:`

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: "navigation-path",
    template: "{{los}}",
    style: "irrelevant"]
})

export class NavigationPathComponent {
    @Input() los: string;
}
```

And inside LeaderComponent template there is:

`<navigation-path los="someString"></navigation-path>`

Which should result in that if I will add `{{los}}` into `<navigation-path>` template it should output `someString` in browser but instead it outputs nothing. Although if I log it out inside component code it will output `someString` into console.

P.S. If I move `<navigation-path>` into AppComponent template (one nesting level higher) it works perfectly. Is it even possible to nest components inside already nested component in Angular? Currently I'm working on Angular v4.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [] syntax around the property when passing it through: 
Which would be [los]="someString".

Comment: Then why is it visible inside components code, but not in template?

P.S. Unfortunately your advice didn't work. :(

Comment: The code looks fine to me. I have always used a templateUrl with a html page. Try console logging the "los" on  initialisation of the NavigationPathComponent using ngOnInit.

Comment: The thing is that it HAS a value. It logs someString into console (or alert depends on how I decide to display it.